# Pytorch Transformer won't train due to tensor sizes

Tags: nlp, pytorch, tensor, transformer-model

I tried following this tutorial for transformers:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0s0f995w14

However, when I try to train the code with my own vectors, I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File >"C:\Users\rreichel\Desktop\Smaragd_local\Programming\Scripts\Transformer_se>lfbuilt.py", line 279, in 
> loss = loss_func(outputs, target)
>
> File "C:\Users\rreichel\Anaconda3\lib\site->packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
> result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\rreichel\Anaconda3\lib\site->packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 1047, in forward
> return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
>
> File "C:\Users\rreichel\Anaconda3\lib\site->packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2693, in cross_entropy
> return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, >ignore_index, None, reduction)
>
> File "C:\Users\rreichel\Anaconda3\lib\site->packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2397, in nll_loss
> raise ValueError("Expected target size {}, got {}".format(out_size, >target.size()))
>
> ValueError: Expected target size (3, 199), got torch.Size([3, 119])
> when calculating the loss during training.

The code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Apr  6 08:13:38 2021

@author: rreichel
"""

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import pickle
import glob
import os
from SelfbuiltDataset_test import myDataset
import torch.optim as optim


class SelfAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_size, heads):
        super(SelfAttention, self).__init__()
        self.embed_size = embed_size
        self.heads = heads
        self.head_dim = embed_size // heads

        assert(self.head_dim * heads == embed_size
        ), "Embedding size needs to be divisible by heads"

        self.values = nn.Linear(self.head_dim, self.head_dim, bias=False)
        self.keys = nn.Linear(self.head_dim, self.head_dim, bias=False)
        self.queries = nn.Linear(self.head_dim, self.head_dim, bias=False)
        self.fc_out = nn.Linear(heads * self.head_dim, embed_size)

    def forward(self, values, keys, query, mask):
        #Get number of training examples
        N = query.shape[0]

        value_len, key_len, query_len = values.shape[1], keys.shape[1], \
        query.shape[1]

        #Split the embedding into self.heads different pieces
        values = values.reshape(N, value_len, self.heads, self.head_dim)
        keys = keys.reshape(N, key_len, self.heads, self.head_dim)
        query = query.reshape(N, query_len, self.heads, self.head_dim)

        #(N, value_len, heads, head_dim)
        values = self.values(values)
        #(N, key_len, heads, head_dim)
        keys = self.keys(keys)
        #(N, query_len, heads, heads_dim)
        queries = self.queries(query)

        energy = torch.einsum("nqhd, nkhd -> nhqk", [queries, keys])
        #queries shape: (N, query_len, heads, heads_dim),
        #keys shape: (N, key_len, heads, heads_dim)
        #energy: (N, heads, query_len, key_len)

        #Mask padded indices so their weights become 0
        if mask is not None:
            energy = energy.masked_fill(mask == 0, float("-1e20"))

        #Normalize energy values
        attention = torch.softmax(energy / (self.embed_size ** (1 / 2)), dim=3)
        #attention shape: (N, heads, query_len, key_len)

        out = torch.einsum("nhql, nlhd -> nqhd", [attention, values]).reshape(
            N, query_len, self.heads * self.head_dim)
        #attention shape: (N, heads, query_len, key_len)
        #values shape: (N, value_len, heads, heads_dim)
        #out after matrix multiply: (N, query_len, heads, head_dim), then
        #we reshape and flatten the last two dimensions.

        out = self.fc_out(out)

        return out


class TransformerBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_size, heads, dropout, forward_expansion):
        super(TransformerBlock, self).__init__()
        self.attention = SelfAttention(embed_size, heads)
        self.norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(embed_size)
        self.norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(embed_size)

        self.feed_forward = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(embed_size, forward_expansion * embed_size),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(forward_expansion * embed_size, embed_size))

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, value, key, query, mask):
        attention = self.attention(value, key, query, mask)

        # Add skip connection, run through normalization and finally dropout
        x = self.dropout(self.norm1(attention + query))
        forward = self.feed_forward(x)
        out = self.dropout(self.norm2(forward + x))
        return out


class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, src_vocab_size, embed_size, num_layers, heads, device,
        forward_expansion, dropout, max_length):

        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.embed_size = embed_size
        self.device = device
        self.word_embedding = nn.Embedding(src_vocab_size, embed_size)
        self.position_embedding = nn.Embedding(max_length, embed_size)

        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([TransformerBlock(embed_size, heads,
                    dropout=dropout, forward_expansion=forward_expansion)
                    for _ in range(num_layers)])

        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, x, mask):
        N, seq_length = x.shape
        positions = torch.arange(0, seq_length).expand(N, seq_length).to(self.device)
        out = self.dropout(
            (self.word_embedding(x) +
             self.position_embedding(positions))
        )

        #In the Encoder the query, key, value are all the same, it's in the
        #decoder this will change. This might look a bit odd in this case.
        for layer in self.layers:
            out = layer(out, out, out, mask)

        return out


class DecoderBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_size, heads, forward_expansion, dropout, device):
        super(DecoderBlock, self).__init__()
        self.norm = nn.LayerNorm(embed_size)
        self.attention = SelfAttention(embed_size, heads=heads)
        self.transformer_block = TransformerBlock(embed_size, heads, dropout,
                                                  forward_expansion)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, x, value, key, src_mask, trg_mask):
        attention = self.attention(x, x, x, trg_mask)
        query = self.dropout(self.norm(attention + x))
        out = self.transformer_block(value, key, query, src_mask)
        return out


class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, trg_vocab_size, embed_size, num_layers, heads,
        forward_expansion, dropout, device, max_length):
        
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.device = device
        self.word_embedding = nn.Embedding(trg_vocab_size, embed_size)
        self.position_embedding = nn.Embedding(max_length, embed_size)

        self.layers = nn.ModuleList([DecoderBlock(embed_size, heads,
                                                  forward_expansion, dropout,
                                                  device)
                for _ in range(num_layers)])
        
        self.fc_out = nn.Linear(embed_size, trg_vocab_size)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, x, enc_out, src_mask, trg_mask):
        N, seq_length = x.shape
        positions = torch.arange(0, seq_length).expand(N,seq_length).to(self.device)
        x = self.dropout((self.word_embedding(x) +
                          self.position_embedding(positions)))

        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x, enc_out, enc_out, src_mask, trg_mask)

        out = self.fc_out(x)

        return out


class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, src_vocab_size, trg_vocab_size, src_pad_idx,
                 trg_pad_idx, embed_size=512, num_layers=6,
                 forward_expansion=4, heads=8, dropout=0, device="cpu",
                 max_length=100):

        super(Transformer, self).__init__()

        self.encoder = Encoder(src_vocab_size, embed_size, num_layers, heads,
                               device, forward_expansion, dropout, max_length)

        self.decoder = Decoder(trg_vocab_size, embed_size, num_layers, heads,
                               forward_expansion, dropout, device, max_length)

        self.src_pad_idx = src_pad_idx
        self.trg_pad_idx = trg_pad_idx
        self.device = device

    def make_src_mask(self, src):
        #(N, 1, 1, src_len)
        src_mask = (src != self.src_pad_idx).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2)
        return src_mask.to(self.device)

    def make_trg_mask(self, trg):
        N, trg_len = trg.shape
        trg_mask = torch.tril(torch.ones((trg_len, trg_len))).expand(N, 1,
                                                            trg_len, trg_len)

        return trg_mask.to(self.device)

    def forward(self, src, trg):
        src_mask = self.make_src_mask(src)
        trg_mask = self.make_trg_mask(trg)
        enc_src = self.encoder(src, src_mask)
        out = self.decoder(trg, enc_src, src_mask, trg_mask)
        return out

def nextMultiple(n, x):
    n = n + x / 2
    n = n - (n % x)
    return int(n)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    """
    #This shit are the one-hot encoded sentences (word 1, word 4 etc. as sentence)
    train = torch.tensor([[1, 5, 6, 4, 3, 9, 5, 2, 0, 1, 11],
                      [1, 8, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 2, 1, 3]]).to(device)
    target = torch.tensor([[1, 7, 4, 3, 5, 9, 2, 0, 2, 2],
                        [1, 5, 6, 2, 4, 7, 6, 2, 9, 1]]).to(device)
    max_len = max([len(x) for x in train]) + 1
    
    """
    #Loading in data
    data = pickle.load(open('Testdaten.pkl', 'rb'))
    tmp = myDataset(data, 'POS')
    #Calculating maximum sentence length (+ 1 because of start tag)
    max_len = max([len(x) for x in tmp.sent_encoded]) + 1
    pad_element = len(tmp.lookup_words)
    
    #Padding everything out to maximum sentence length
    train_tmp = []
    for sent in tmp.sent_encoded:
        train_tmp.append([pad_element] + sent + [pad_element] * (max_len - len(sent) - 1))
    target_tmp = []
    for sent in tmp.tags_encoded:
        target_tmp.append(sent + [pad_element] * (max_len - len(sent) - 1))
        
    #Creating tensors for model
    train = torch.squeeze(torch.tensor(train_tmp))
    target = torch.squeeze(torch.tensor(target_tmp))
    #"""
    src_pad_idx = 0
    trg_pad_idx = 0
    src_vocab_size = int(torch.max(train)) + 1
    trg_vocab_size = int(torch.max(target)) + 1
    heads = 8
    es = nextMultiple(max(src_vocab_size, trg_vocab_size), heads)
    
    model = Transformer(src_vocab_size, trg_vocab_size, src_pad_idx,
                        trg_pad_idx, es, 3, 2, heads, 0.1, device,
                        max_len).to(device)
    
    #Defining loss function and optimizer
    lr = 0.001
    num_epochs = 2
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr, momentum=0.9)
    loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    
    # optimization algorithm
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    # train and evaluation
    for cnt in range(num_epochs):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = model(train, target)
        outputs = outputs
        #Outputs now are size[3, 119, 119]
        #CrossEntropyLoss mag one-hot-encoding nicht, how to deal with this?
        loss = loss_func(outputs, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    #out = model(train, target)
    #print(out.shape)
```

I am confused since the code works with the vectors from the tutorial, but once I try to run the model with my own vocabulary, it produces this strange error. The data is just integer values encoding the corresponding words, e.g. "Hello World" would result in the training vector [1 2].

There is no differences between my data and the data from the tutorial as far as I can see. The tensor types are the same (Torch.LongTensor), they are both integer values and in a specified range. The difference is in dimensionality, the tutorial uses vectors with dimension (2, 10), while mine are (3, 199).

Also, I am sorry, but I can't reduce the code any more since otherwise, the error might not be reproduceable.

Did anyone encounter this error before?

Comment: Always share full error message!

Comment: Hello, can you please highlight the difference between your inputs and those from the tutorial ? Hardly anybody will watch the hour-long video. Can you also try to make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ? This code snippet is quite long